# css rule not applying when using third party files

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the following [source](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/01/08/inspiration-text-input-effects/) to create some good looking forms on my site.

If you look at the live demo, and go to the form titled "yoko" you will see that once you fill out the input box, it is supposed to stay open, and you are supposed to be able to see the text you input.

When I use this source, it opens when I click in the text box, but the form collapses even when it has been filled out, which it is not supposed to do.

On the demo when you click in the text box and fill it out, the class name of that span element goes from "input input--minoru" to "input input--minoru input--filled". When I use the css, and javascript files from the source the forms open up correctly when I click and type in them, but they do not stay open, and the class title does not changed to "input input--minoru input--filled".

In my header.php I all the css files in the following order:

```
<link href="dist3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" >
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/component.css" >
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css" >
```

In my index.php I have the following piece of code:

```
<section class="test">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="input input--minoru">
          <input class="input__field input__field--yoko" type="text" id="input-1" />
          <label class="input__label input__label--yoko" for="input-1">
              <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--yoko">First Name</span>
          </label>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <span class="input input--yoko">
          <input class="input__field input__field--yoko" type="text" id="input-1" />
          <label class="input__label input__label--yoko" for="input-1">
              <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--yoko">Last Name</span>
          </label>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

and at the very end of index.php I call the javascript files in this order:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/classie.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

The styles are all applying, so I know the css is at least styling correctly, but it is not doing the correct `::before and ::after`  functionality correctly.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6rvmy3f/) of what I am talking about

If you type in something into a form, and then leave the input area the box collapses again. When it should stay up.

I did not include the .js files, but classie.js comes with the source, and they are ordered as mentioned above in my index.php

Comment: are those all the .css files and .js files you are using?

Comment: yes it those are all @indubitablee

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle to demo the issue you are experiencing? or perhaps show us the site on which this is happening? (the one where it collapses even when content is filled out) so that we can better debug it

Comment: I have added a JSFiddle as an example @indubitablee

Comment: sorry ._. i have no idea whats going on. i even tried to overwrite what was happening with my own jquery but no luck. sorry, good luck with the issue